# Como disminuir zoom en simulador de iPhone en Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy empezando en la programación de `Xcode` y me encontré con que no puedo disminuir el zoom del simulador ya que tengo una `Mac` pero como monitor uso un `LG` por lo que el simulador no se muestra por completo en la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

intenta presionando command + 1,2,3 o 4 cuando estes en el simulador